# What does the dot-slash do to PHP include calls?

Tags: php, url, include, relative-path

A. What does this do?

```
require ("./file.php");
```

B. in comparison to this?

```
require ("file.php");
```

---

(Its **not** up-one-directory.. which would be)

```
require ("../file.php");
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`./` is the *current* directory. It is largely the same as just `file.php`, but in many cases (this one included) it doesn't check any standard places PHP might look for a file, instead checking *only* the current directory.

From the [PHP documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (notice the last sentence):

> Files for including are first looked for in each include_path entry relative to the current working directory, and then in the directory of current script. E.g. if your include_path is libraries, current working directory is /www/, you included include/a.php and there is include "b.php"  in that file, b.php is first looked in /www/libraries/  and then in /www/include/. If filename begins with ./ or ../, it is looked only in the current working directory.

Comment: so, the require ("./file.php"); is faster than require ("file.php"); ?

Answer (score 9):

The first version forces the internal mechanism to include files relatively to the... directly executed file. So for example you have

**index.php**

```
// directly executed script (php -f index.php or from a browser)
include 'second.php';
```

**second.php**

```
// This is included relatively to index.php
// Actually, it is first searched relatively to include_path, then relatively
// to index.php
include './third.php';
```

**third.php**

```
// This is included relatively to second.php ONLY. It does not search
// include_path
return "foo";
```

Comment: I had a few mistakes that I've now corrected, the order of search was wrong. The proof is the answer above mine.

Comment: In `third.php` comment is actually wrong. `third.php` is actually included relatively to `index.php` only.
Actually, even that is wrong. It is actually included relatively to the **current working directory** only.
For example, if `index.php` is located in `/var/www/index.php`. And you cd to other directory, (eg. `cd /var`) and then you try to execute `index.php` by `php www/index.php`, THEN when you do `include './third.php'`, php will try to find it in `/var` directory and fail if it's not there

Answer (score 7):

**The Short Answer**

You're right, it's not up one directory.  A `.` refers to the directory you're in, and `..` refers to the parent directory.

Meaning, `./file.php` and `file.php` are functionally equivalent in PHP.  Here's the relavent page of documentation:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php

**The Longer Answer**

However, just because they work the same in this context doesn't mean they're always the same.

When you're operating in a *nix shell environment, and you type the name of an executable file, the shell will look in the `PATH` directories, but it won't look in the `CWD`, or the directory you're currently in.

So, if you're in a directory that has a file called: `myprogram.php` (this would be a PHP CLI file) and you just type:

`myprogram.php`

it doesn't matter if your program is executable or not.  The shell will look in `/bin/`, `/usr/bin/`, etc. for your file, but it won't look in `./`: the directory you're in.

To execute that program without adding your directory to the PATH, you need to type

`./myprogram`

So really, `./` is more explicit.  It means, "the file you're looking for HAS to be right here" and lack of `./` means, "the file should be somewhere the program is looking for files".

Answer (score 5):

The dot-slash forces the file to be found in the current directory only, rather than additionally searching the paths mentioned in the include_path setting.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**: I have completely rewritten the answer for the sake of clarity

---

When including a file, you can either use `./myfile.php` or `myfile.php`.

They are not the same and you should always, preferably, use the first syntax, unless you know what you're doing.

The difference is best illustrated with an example: lets say you have the following files and folder structure:

```
index.php
inc/inner.php
```

From `index.php`, you can include your inner template without the ' `./`'  and it will work as expected:

```php
# index.php
<?php
include "inc/inner.php";
```

Now let's say we add a new file, so the folder structure is now like this:

```
index.php
inc/inner.php
inc/inner-inner.php
```

To include `inner-inner.php` in `inner.php`, we would do this... right?

```php
# src/inner.php
<?php
include "inner-inner.php";
```

**Wrong**. `inner.php` will just look for `inner-inner.php` *in the **root** folder*.

```
index.php
* inner-inner.php <- Doesn't exist, PHP ERROR.
inc/inner.php
inc/inner-inner.php
```

Instead, we should use the `./` syntax to include inner-inner. This will instruct that the file we are including must be included **relative to the current file, not to the current "entry point"** of the PHP script (`index.php` in the example).

```
# src/inner.php
<?php
include "./inner-inner.php";
```

In addition, and as mentioned in other comments, if you have configured a different "load path" for your PHP application, that load path will be looked up first without the `./` syntax. Instead, the `./` syntax is more efficient because it doesn't check the "include path" of php <sup>*[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)*</sup>.

If you wanna make your includes even more explicit, use the `__DIR__` constant. This tells php: "Use the directory of this file" <sup>*[2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php)*</sup>.

```php
# src/inner.php
<?php
include __DIR__ . "/inner-inner.php";
```

---

> **TLDR;** Always use `./` or `__DIR__` <sup>*[2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php)*</sup> because it's relative to the current (working) directory and doesn't depend on the PHP "include path" <sup>*[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)*</sup>.

---

*References:*

1. [Include - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php]
2. [Magic Constants - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: You saved me typing a new answer, thank you. This is by far the best answer, because while most developers don't care for that extra millisecond gained when not searching in include_path, the biggest problems and misunderstanding with PHP in these here regard arise when nesting several includes. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

Simply you are telling php to include the file in the current directory **only** or fail if the file is not present.

If you use the format "indexcommon3.php" and the file is not present php will search it into the include_path system variable.

For reference you can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

It's explicitly naming the *current* directory.