# Difference between ./ and ../ in PHP

Tags: php, linux, file, path

I wanted to ask whats the difference between

```
include('./config.php')
```

and

```
include('../config.php')
```

The 2nd one goes one dir up and includes from folder one level higher. But what Exacly does one dot do?

Edit; Thank you everyone for you answers. It brightened my mind a bit. I chose answer that was most infomative about topic (especially in PHP enviroment)

Comment: the `./` is for current folder.

Comment: so does include('./config.php') and include('config.php') do exacly same?

Comment: Theoretically they should, yes.

Comment: I would take the time here to explain the difference between all 4 access methods... no characters in front, `/`, `./`, and `../`

Comment: It is surely a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe wouldnt duplicate, if somone did not write dot-slash ... didnt think of writing it like it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a system thing and NOT just a PHP thing.

The `./` indicates the current directory. If you ever list the contents of a *nix system you will get the following at the top.

```
.
../
```

The top one (`.`) is the same as `./` which means "this directory". So if including a file like such:

```
include('./config.php')
```

You are telling PHP to look in the current directory for "config.php". Which is the same as

```
include('config.php')
```

The `../` indicates the directory above or "parent directory"

```
include('../config.php')
```

This is telling PHP to go one directory up and look for "config.php". These commands can be chained like so:

```
../../config.php
```

This tells the system to go up one directory, go up again and then look for "config.php"

Comment: Hmm, wondering now. In PHP when you include file, it includes file that is relative to the file that is Executed, not included.
Basicly, when I have file 
test/index.php
and include
test/library/config.php
and in this file I include file with or without ./ it will look for files in test/ directory in both cases?

Comment: @Gacek, yes. When including a file, it's as if the contents of the script is in the current file. If you need relative to the included file, use `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: I know about dirname(__FILE__). just was wondering aboug difference between ./ and without. If there is any difference except some people write it and some do not.
Mostyl I always try to include absolute path since in case of executing script from CLI it will not fond files unless in right directory.

Comment: @Gacek oh.. read your second question wrong. the `./` is better (IMO) but is not needed. With or without is still using relative path

Comment: I know ./ is used to ./configure and executing scripts in unixes, since configure only would not work. so I was wondering if it has anything to do in this case :)

Comment: @Gacek The `./` is needed when going to execute a script. In this case, you're only including

Answer (score 11):

In posix file systems `.` simply means current directory and `..` means parent directory.

Answer (score 3):

One dot refers to the current directory.

```
include('./config.php')
```

is basically the same as

```
include('config.php')
```

Comment: Is there **any** difference?

Comment: Thank you, thats basicly what I wanted to know. Just put a bit wrong question it seems :)

Comment: @Nicholas Pickering See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/579398/881229

Answer (score 1):

`.` means the *current directory*

`..` means the *parent directory*

It is not about PHP, it is OS convention that is called [**dot directory name**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee381481)

> **"dirA\.\dirB"** is equivalent to **"dirA\dirB"**.
>
> **"dirA\dirB\..\dirC"** is equivalent to **"dirA\dirC"**.

Answer (score 0):

```
include('../config.php') :- parent directory
include('./config.php') :- current directory
```

Answer (score 0):

`./` is for the current directory

`../` is for going to the parent directory of the current one

For answering your question, suppose you don't write `.`

`include('/config.php')` would include the 'config.php' file in the root of the filesystem