# Header Location is not working properly even when everything looks ok in code

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

I have the following folder structure

```
/main/site/
```

the redirect script is in the following dir

```
/main/site/backend/

header('Location: ../register.php');
```

returns to `/main/register.php/` when it should go to `/main/site/register.php`

It seems all ok in the code , since `../` should go back one dir,

someone know what is wrong?

Comment: Does the server do any URL rewriting? The URL in the redirect is processed by the client, it doesn't know anything about server-side rewrites.

Comment: URL rewriting not in both folders, I have a regex expresssion but it's in another site folder

Comment: So the URL in the browser's address bar is something like `https://www.example.com/main/site/backend/filename.php`?

Comment: exactly, the url is: `https://www.example.com/main/site/backend/filename.php`

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter where your script resides - every `Location` instruction applies to what the outside looks like. If the script is requested thru `https://www.example.com/main/site/backend/filename.php` then it must redirect to `../../register.php` or even better `/main/register.php`.

Comment: And "not work" means what? The HTTP logic is correct in there, but nobody knows if you end your PHP script properly or what the internet browser in question does (check https://stackoverflow.com/a/56790467/4299358 )

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this

```
header('Location: ./../register.php');
```

`./` Forces PHP to look only in current directory

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579374/what-does-the-dot-slash-do-to-php-include-calls)

Comment: still got the same dir

Comment: How about `header('Location: '. __DIR__ . '../register.php')`